# I cannot figure this while loop out in C

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf, do-while

I am new to programming in C and I am currently just working on a problem set for a rental business. I am trying to ask for what type of car, choice between only 3, and calculating total rental cost for one vehicle. I think, I need a while loop followed by several if statements but, I am currently able to compile the code but, it only runs until the first input is entered. Any guidance is helpful, I am not looking for the solution just where I need to focus my attention. While loops throw me for a loop ;)

```
int type, daysRented, numberOfMiles, rentalTotal, totalRevenue = 0;

do{
    printf("Enter 0 for End, 1 for sports car, 2 for midsize, 3 for economy: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &type);
    
} while (type != 0);

printf("Enter days rented: ");
scanf("%d\n", &daysRented);
printf("Enter the number of miles: ");
scanf("%d\n", &numberOfMiles);

if (type == 1){
    rentalTotal = (daysRented * 75) + (numberOfMiles * 2);
    printf("%i\n", totalRevenue);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not a `while` loop, that's a `do`/`while` loop. You should indent your code with an autoformatter. People are generally unhappy when asked to debug code with poor indentation.

What this code actually does is run the prompt and `scanf` line until a number other than zero is provided, but the prompt says it does something else.

You probably want:

```
while(1){
    do{
        type = -1;
        printf("Enter 0 for End, 1 for sports car, 2 for midsize, 3 for economy: ");
        scanf("%d", &type);        
    } while (type < 0 || type > 3);
    if (type == 0) break;
    // The rest of the stuff here ...
}
```

Thus testing if `type` is in range or not, and going back to the top after the first run.

So there's actually more to the question than I though. The `scanf` format line is wrong. The loop behaved itself after I removed the `\n` from that format specifier. I made the following change and it started behaving itself:

```
    scanf("%d", &type);        
    getc(stdin); /* throw away newline */
```

I typically recommend discarding scanf in favor of writing simple input functions for reading a line, an integer, and a double as soon as you learn function input, which shouldn't be very far off.

Comment: Thank you Josh, can you elaborate on where you said that the prompt say it does something else? I believe that is where I am most confused about loops.

Comment: @jrochau Work through it by hand. See what it does.

Comment: I have and I am not seeing what I am doing wrong. I have implemented the code you have suggested and I am still able to compile it but it stalls in the same spot as my previous code. I enter the first round of numbers 1, 2, or 3 and it stops.

Comment: @jrochau: Ah. It's also a scanf question.